# How to exclude posts from a category when using this particular format

Tags: categories, exclude

I'm trying to exclude posts from a certain category from being displayed on my home.php.

The code that is in my theme is as follows:

```
query_posts(array('post__not_in' => $featured_posts_array));
                if (have_posts()) :
                    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                            <div class="categories">
                                <h3><?php the_categories_excerpt(); ?></h3>
```

I tried adding the following before the query_posts ( function but it does nothing.

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( is_feed() ) {
        $query = set_query_var( 'cat', '-1' );  
    }

    return $query;
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

Is there some kind of format I need to follow?

Comment: So would this be the right format then? http://pastebin.com/cLpGvnRD

And in the home.php, i'll be replacing the query_post section with this: filter_pre_get_posts()

Comment: No. Your Pastebin code isn't what I've got in my answer. And you don't *ever* need to call `query_posts()`, *anywhere*. (I'll update my answer to incorporate your featured posts function.)

Comment: Alright.. got it now. had to remove that piece of line
`query_posts(array('post__not_in' => $featured_posts_array));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, **don't use `query_posts()`**. Just get rid of the call entirely. It will break things.

Second:

> I tried adding the following before the query_posts ( function but it does nothing.

Callbacks and `add_action()` calls belong in **`functions.php`**, *not* in the template file. If you've put it directly in `home.php`, remove it from there, and put it in `functions.php`.

Third:

Your `pre_get_posts()` filter uses the `if ( is_feed() )` conditional. The [**`is_feed()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_feed) conditional returns true when an RSS feed is being output, *not* on the blog posts index (which is what is output via `home.php`). Try using [**`is_home()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) instead.

Fourth:

Don't call `set_query_var()` inside your callback. Use `$query->set()` instead.

#### Putting it all together

Use the following in `functions.php`

```
<?php
function wpse55358_filter_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    // Let's only modify the main query
    if ( ! is_main_query() ) {
        return $query;
    }
    // Modify the blog posts index query
    if ( is_home() ) {
        // Exclude Category ID 1
        $query->set( 'cat', '-1' );

        // Build featured posts array
        $featured_posts_array = featured_posts_slider();

        // Exclude featured posts
        $query->set( 'post__not_in', $featured_posts_array );
    }
    // Return the query object
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse55358_filter_pre_get_posts' );
?>
```

#### Questions

What category are you trying to exclude? Are you sure the ID is `1`?

Comment: Another thing to note - you will almost always want to also check for `$query->is_main_query()` right away when altering the query via `pre_get_posts`. Otherwise you might affect secondary queries unintentionally (e.g. a nav menu).

Comment: I've updated the answer to incorporate `featured_posts_slider()`.